# How do I get rid of white spots in hair particles

Tags: particles, hair

I am using two hairs particle systems and get these these weird white spots from the hair particles? I'm using the principled shader for the hairs and don't use any denoising when I render. I tried using higher sample count but that doesn't make it go away. Does anybody know why I get these spots and how to get rid of them.

[image]

Comment: R U talking about the fact that the hair looks like wolf hair or something and not plain black?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard no I'm talking about the weird white spots as if the hairs got little cuts of space.

Comment: Oh, that? Those gaps in the hair are actually physically there, so if you want to get rid of them, you need to turn up your render resolution: the holes are really there.

Comment: yeah, the hairs are passing in front of each other, creating little spaces that are visible. They become more noticeable on lower resolutions, because each gap (which would be a few small pixels) is now a couple of larger pixels (in an attempt to keep them there for detail's sake). Up your resolution and it should help. Some anti aliasing should help making it look less 'harsh'.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try to fix it